# Can I dynamically name a terraform resource?

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-gcp

I am working with terraform on GCP. I want to be able to create a new Jenkins worker and have it named jenkins-worker-*
where the * is the number of the instance.

Is there a way to do this dynamically? I assume there isn't and I'll just have to change my variables.tf file to change the number of the host I'm working with.

Comment: Will you be creating all worker instances using this terraform script? If so, can't you just use [`count`](https://www.terraform.io/language/meta-arguments/count)? And if not… how are you going to avoid numbering conflicts with the other entity that's creating these worker?

Comment: No, you can't do that.

Comment: I will be creating all worker instances with that script